# Cannot find module 'chart.js'.) Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, charts, angular-chart

hey folks i'm using the Angular2 CLI and trying to import the chart.js module but every time i run up the server I get a '**cannot find module "chart.js"**'

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import Chart from 'chart.js';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html'
 })

 export class AppComponent {
   title = 'Test';
   let myChart = new Chart({});
};
```

Comment: Try: import 'chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js';  Assuming you did an npm install of chartjs already.

Comment: i did npm install it but didn't fix it. I need to import Chart from it's directory

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you may have incorrectly declared your Chart import

You have:

```
import Chart from 'chart.js';
```

But it should be:

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
```

Also check that you have the chart.js npm package installed, if you don't have it properly installed, you can install it with:

```
npm install chart.js --save
```